# Python. Gtk 3. Как заблокировать закрытие окна

Tags: python, gtk

Как в *GTK 3* заблокировать закрытие окна через сочетание клавишей *ALT+F4*?

Answer (score 1):

Alt-F4 это сочетание клавиш перехватывает ОС и в программу посылает сигнал о  завершении работы программы. Поэтому чтобы управлять "сочетанием клавиш Alt-F4" нужно управлять входящими сигналами. А здесь зависит от ОС в которой работаешь, а не от GTK.

Comment: В *tkinter* есть *protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",self.func_pass)*. Через него я ссылался на функцию, где было прописано `pass` и оно не закрывалось. Есть ли такое же в GTK 3?

Comment: в GTK такой возможности нет, но можно обрабатывать события из библиотеки GDK  там есть события (Event DELETE)